# Characteristic polynomial on Direct sum of Operators

Tags: linear-algebra, characteristic-polynomial

Let $T:V \rightarrow V$ be an linear operator. If $T = T_{1} \bigoplus T_{2}$ then $p_T(x)=p_{T_{1}}(x)\cdot p_{T_{2}}(x)$ where $p_T$ is the characteristic polynomial of T.

My attempt: By Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $p_T(T) = p_{T}(T_{1} \bigoplus T_{2}) = p_{T}(T_{1}) \bigoplus p_{T}(T_{2}) = 0$ then $p_{T}(T_1) = 0$ and $p_T(T_2) = 0$. So, we have that the minimal polynomial $m_{T_1}$ of $T_1$and $m_{T_2}$ of $T_2$ divides $p_T$, then $$p_T = \operatorname{lcm}(m_{T_1},m_{T_2}).$$ But how can I come up with $p_{T} = p_{T_1}p_{T_2}$? Does I need to use the fact that $\operatorname{dim}(T) = \operatorname{dim}(T_1)+\operatorname{dim}(T_2)$?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What does $\oplus$ means? Composition?

Comment: @Zanzag It means a [direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum)

Comment: @Dazai What exactly is your definition of the characteristic polynomial? Could we make use of the determinant formula $\det(T_1 \oplus T_2) = \det(T_1)\det(T_2)$?

Comment: Using the Cayley-Hamilton theorem alone will not work, I think. The characteristic polynomial is *not* uniquely determined by $p_T(T) = 0$ and the dimension alone. As you noticed, this might help you with the minimal polynomial, but in general, there are several possibilities for the characteristic polynomial for a given minimal polynomial and dimension of the space. You will need to go back to the definition of the characteristic polynomial.